# Boost property tree count does not count the childs?

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I have a json that looks like this:

```
{"field":{"val1":25, "val2":48, "name1":"qqd"}}
```

When I do a verification of the received json has the specific fields like this:

```
std::size_t fcnt = pt.count("field");
std::size_t val1cnt = pt.count("field.val1");
std::size_t val2cnt = pt.count("field.val2");
std::size_t nm1cnt = pt.count("field.name1");
std::cout << fcnt << val1cnt << val2cnt << nm1cnt << std::endl; // this is just for testing
if (fcnt != 1 || val1cnt != 1 || val2cnt != 1 || nm1cnt !=1)
  throw BadJSONFormatException();
```

I get always the exception and the values printed are: `1000`. Why? `count` does not work like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs says: "Count the number of direct children with the given key."

In other words, the string you pass is a simple key, not a path. Dots won't get special handling.

I think letting ptree have the dual container/path interface is the largest problem it has. I see so much confusion over it. Something to consider for the next version.

Comment: Personally, I have never found a use case where Boost Property Tree was actually the right solution. For XML, use e.g. PugiXML (headeronly!). For JSON use any json parser, For INI file, use a trivial parser (I have 2 or so in SO answers :)). In my eyes, the functionality of Property Tree is basically crippled for any of these back ends, with little/no control over roundtrip fidelity. And it has the API quirks to boot.

Comment: The only things I'd say it has got going for it is (a) it's in boost (b) it has a single interface (though that is a very leaky abstraction!) (c) it has a wchar_t leg OotB.

Comment: Actually I think that you should not consider the property tree a parser for some configuration file but as a container. The fact that that container can be filled from different source formats is important but not fundamental. In my use case I use it as a versatile container for the configuration parameters of the concrete implementation of my interfaces